# js function stacks passed in variables, .hide() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, console.log

I have a function that plays the video when i click on the video thumbnail image. I am attempting to show/hide the video description that is generated dynamically trough php, but it seems to not work.

Setup: wordpres cms with jwplayer7.

This is the html that calls the js function

```
<div class="s_l_whole_item" title="sample.mp4" onclick="playVOD(this.id)" id="sample.mp4"> video image here </div>
```

All the javascript is in external file and this is the function that plays the video and should show /hide(not implemented yet, but even hide doesn't work) the divs that has been created for each video dynamically

```
function playVOD(filename) {
    jwplayer('MediaPlayerOverview_LS_dvr')
            .setup(
                    {
                        sources : [
                                {
                                    file : "rtmp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1935/vod/mp4:"+ filename
                                },
                                {
                                    file : "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1935/vod/mp4:"
                                            + filename + "/playlist.m3u8"
                                } ],
                        rtmp : {
                            bufferlength : 3,
                        },
                        logo : {
                            file : 'http://www.somepicture.nu/a.jpg',
                            link : 'http://www.link.nu/'
                        },
                        abouttext : "right click text",
                        aboutlink : "http://www.right click link.com",
                        autostart : true,
                        title : 'title',
                        width : '100%',
                        height : "100%",
                        aspectratio : '16:9',
                        skin : 'glow',
                        fallback : true,
                        androidhls : true,

                    })

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            jQuery('.s_l_whole_item').live('click', function(event) {
                //jQuery(this).closest('.hiden_karuselis').find('#ka_'+filename).toggle();

                jQuery(this).closest('.hiden_karuselis').find('#ka_'+filename).hide();

                 console.log("I have been clicked!");
                 console.log('#ka_'+filename);

            });
        });

}
```

The video playback works on each different click, and it plays the video i click on, but it does not show/hide the divs for some reason.

this is the div i am trying to hide/show depending on what video has been clicked. For demonstration purposes lets say its just "sample.mp4"

```
<div class="hiden_karuselis">
 <div class="ka_file" id="ka_sample.mp4">
  <div class="ka_file_name">sample</div>
  <div class="ka_file_description">description of file</div>
  <div class="ka_file_date">2016-04-19 10:19:33</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

After unsuccessful tries i noticed that the chrome console outputs the variables as if the function would be appending to it self all previous calls.
This is what i see in console when clicking 3 times on 3 different videos.

```
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:77 I have been clicked!
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:78 #ka_sample.mp4
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:77 I have been clicked!
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:78 #ka_sample.mp4
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:77 I have been clicked!
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:78 #ka_myStream.mp4
VM9740:13 Unhandled event from "MediaPlayerOverview_LS_dvr_swf_0": state %7B%22newstate%22%3A%22idle%22%2C%22oldstate%22%3A%22playing%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22state%22%7D
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:77 I have been clicked!
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:78 #ka_sample.mp4
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:77 I have been clicked!
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:78 #ka_myStream.mp4
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:77 I have been clicked!
vod_player.js?ver=4.4.3:78 #ka_rtgwait.mp4
VM9823:13 Unhandled event from "MediaPlayerOverview_LS_dvr_swf_1": state %7B%22newstate%22%3A%22idle%22%2C%22oldstate%22%3A%22playing%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22state%22%7D
```

In the above log i clicked on the "sample.mp4" then "mystream.mp4" and last on the "rtgwait.mp4"

Why is the .hide() not working and why is there stacking variables in log? Should they not be cleared every time i click on button/ call function ? 
I assume that is also the jwplayer7 error cause and why the .hide() is not working.

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the extra "." in my class name/ID as my id was "filename.mp4". To solve this i had to change how my ID are generated and omit ".mp4" part.

And i also found a solution to show only clicked info.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.s_l_whole_item').live('click', function(event) {
            jQuery('#hiden_karuselis > div').show()
            jQuery('#hiden_karuselis > div').not('#'+filename).hide()
        });
    });
```

Now i have another problem. since i have filenames like

```
 myStream-2015-08-10-08.51.50.076-CEST-0.mp4
```

that is generated by wowza media server. Is there any way to pass "." in as a  part of class/id name and not confuse the css selector?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(filename);` is writing `#ka_sample.mp4` to the console which suggests variable '`filename`' is getting set correctly.

You are then using the filename variable `('#ka_'+filename)`, which would look for an element with ID of #`ka_#ka_sample.mp4`, which doesn't exist.

I'd remove the `'#ka_'` bit so you should have:

```
jQuery(this).closest('.hiden_karuselis').find(filename).hide()
```

Comment: sorry, my bad i will edit the code. the code is console.log('#ka_'+filename);